# NSDictionary and NSMutableDictionary combination

Tags: ios, json, afnetworking

My app uses a `deviceToken` class that is stored in a `dataModel` class. The device token is used via various `AFNetworking commands` through out the app like this.

```
//Notice the syntax for the deviceToken class in this NSDictionary
NSDictionary *params = @{@"cmd":@"join",                            
                         @"token":[_dataModel deviceToken],
```

Below is another way the `[_dataModel deviceToken]` class is used via an `NSMutableDictionary`.

```
NSMutableDictionary* params =[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:command, @"command",                             
[_dataModel deviceToken], @"token", nil ];
```

The thing is my app uses two different APIs and I would like to pass the `[_dataModel deviceToken]` class via j son to a new dictionary. This dictionary currently shows the user's username in the `UILabel` known as `caption`.

```
//This message organizes photos, and shows the users username on them
-(id)initWithIndex:(int)i andData:(NSDictionary*)data
{
self = [super init];
if (self !=nil)
{
    //add the photo caption
    UILabel* caption = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, kThumbSide-32, kThumbSide, 32)];

    caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"username"]];
    [self addSubview: caption];
}
```

I want to format the `UILabel` known as `caption` with the device token, As you can see above, it currently shows the username. The thing is when I try to show the device token in the caption label like this, I get a compiler issue. What's the correct syntax?

```
caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@%@",[data objectForKey:@"token"],[_dataModel deviceToken]];
```

Comment: i think you forgot to add a % symbol in stringWithFormat
`caption.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",[data objectForKey:@"token"],[_dataModel deviceToken]];`

Answer (score 3):

Check the format string in your stringWithFormat: *very carefully*, and it will become obvious that the compiler gave you a correct and very helpful warning. This whole question has nothing whatsoever to do with dictionaries.

BTW. There are no prices for using the smallest amount of lines of code. Using more, simpler statements makes your code a lot easier to debug.